# Why won't core data load in a swiftui class, but it will in a struct view

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

If I put the code below in a struct view, I can use myShows in a swiftui list, but I'm trying to do the same fetch request in a separate class and i get an error if I try to print myShows or myShows[0] or anything like that. I'm assuming it never gets initialized? I'm not sure.

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(
  entity: MyShow.entity(),
  sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyShow.name, ascending: true)
  ]
)
  var myShows: FetchedResults<MyShow>
```

Comment: Would you provide code of entire class and do you instantiate/setup it?

Comment: That's really all the code i have. It just magically works in a swiftui view, but I'm assuming in a separate class, i need to put the fetch request results into myShows, which i can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it 'magically' works in a struct `View` and not a seperate class is because of something like this:

```
ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

This `View` struct has been provided a `\.managedObjectContext` environment object which it can use or pass onto other `View`s (automatically) in it's hierarchy, but not random classes.<sup>*[Ref](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)</sup>
Furthermore, `@FetchRequest` works only when the above environment object has been set.<sup>*[Ref](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/how-to-use-fetchrequest-swiftui)</sup>

So if you try to access the following in a random **class**:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

@FetchRequest(entity: Something.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])) 
var something: FetchedResults<Something>
```

It won't work because it does not inherit the environment automatically as another `View` could.
Hence it can't access the Core Data's `ManagedObjectContext` instance, and thereby `@FetchRequest` will also fail.

To fix this, the crudest way would be to pass on an environment object to the `Class` via it's initializer and then handle it normally inside.
Or you can move to the MVVM pattern and do things a bit differently but that is another topic entirely.
If you are interested, you could have a look at this project that is using Core Data with a simple View Model setup:

- https://github.com/StephenMcMillan/Dub-Dub-Do